# Trying to login to adidas.com with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

So I am trying to login to https://www.adidas.com/us/myaccount-create-or-login I have tried xpath, Name, and ID. So I asked a few friends and one was able to use ID to login but I am still not able to.

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time 
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
import datetime

def getCurrentTime():
    return time.strftime("[%H:%M:%S]")



def ACO(getCurrentTime):
    print("{} Configuration Loaded".format(getCurrentTime()))
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://www.adidas.com/us/myaccount-create-or-login")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("test123")
    driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("test123")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="signinSubmit"]""").click()


    time.sleep(500)
ACO(getCurrentTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

The login form is located *inside an iframe*. In order to locate the elements on this form, you would have to switch to the iframe's context:

```
driver.switch_to.frame("loginaccountframe")

driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("test123")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("test123")
driver.find_element_by_id("signinSubmit").click()
```

As a side note, try to avoid using hardcoded `time.sleep()` timeouts - they are quite unreliable - instead, be explicit with [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) via `WebDriverWait`.